# Dual Space of General $L^p$ Space Which Takes Values in Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Last week, our functional analysis course covered Riesz Representation theorem for $L^p(X,\mu),(1\leq p < \infty)$, namely, $(L^p(X,\mu))^* = L^q(X,\mu)$. And I was stuck with this homework problem to work out the dual space of a  more general version of $L^p$ space:

---

Let $X$ be a Banach space and assume both $X$ and $X^*$ are known, define $L^p([0,1],X)=\{f(t):[0,1]\rightarrow X\big{|}\int_0^1 ||f(t)||^p_X\text{d}t<\infty\}$ where $||\cdot||_X $ is norm in $X$ and define similar $L^p$ norm:$||f||_p =  \big{(}\int_0^1 ||f(t)||^p_X\text{d}t\big{)}^\frac{1}{p}$. The question is to determine what is [$L^p([0,1],X)]^*$?

My first guess is $[L^p([0,1],X)]^*=L^q([0,1],X^*)$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. To begin with, if we are given $g(s)\in L^q([0,1],X^*)$ and define $T_g\in [L^p([0,1],X)]^* $ by 
$$
T_g(f) = \int_0^1 g(s)(f(s)) \text{d}s
$$
Apparently, since each $g(s)$ is a linear functional of $X$,then $T(g)$ is a linear functional. Besides,
\begin{align}
|T_g(f)|\leq\int_{0}^{1} |g(s)(f(s))| \mathrm{d} s &\leq \int_{0}^{1} ||g(s)||_{X^*}\cdot||f(s)||_X \mathrm{d} s\\ \leq (\int_{0}^{1}\|g(s)\|_{X^*}^{q} \mathrm{d} s)^{\frac{1}{q}}\cdot(\int_{0}^{1}\|f(s)\|_{X}^{p} \mathrm{d} s)^{\frac{1}{p}}
 = &||g||_{q}\cdot ||f||_p
\end{align}
I use Hölder's inequality above. This justifies $T(g)\in $[$L^p([0,1],X)]^*$ and $||T_g||\leq ||g||_q$.
However, I got stuck to preceed to verify next two things:

> 1. Find $f \in L^{q}([0,1],X)$ such that $T_g(f) \geq ||g||_q$
> 2. Given $T\in \left[L^{p}([0,1], X)\right]^{*}$, how to find  $g\in L^{q}\left([0,1], X^{*}\right)$ such that $T(f)=\int_{0}^{1} g(s)(f(s)) \mathrm{d} s$ holds for any $f\in L^p([0,1],X)$?

I try to invoke Radon- Nikodym theorem by first defining characteristic funtion $\chi_E(t) = \begin{cases}  x_0 &t\in E\\
0, & t \notin E\end{cases}$, where $x_0$ is a unit vector in $X$ and $E \subset [0,1]$, so we have $\chi_E \in L^{p}([0,1], X)$. Next, we define $\nu(E) = T(\chi_E)$, then we prove $\nu$ is indeed a signed measure and $\nu<< m$, where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure here. By Radon-Nikodym theorem, there exists $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nu(E) = \int_0^1 ||\chi_E(s)||_X\cdot g(t) \text{d}s $  but I hope to get $g:[0,1]\rightarrow X^*$ such that $\nu(E) = \int_0^1  g(s)(\chi_E(s)) \text{d}s $

One reason why the definition $T_g(f)=\int_{0}^{1} g(s)(f(s)) \mathrm{d} s$ might be reasonable is because I can let $X=\mathbb{R}$, then $T_g(f)=\int_{0}^{1} g(s)(f(s)) \mathrm{d} s = \int_{0}^{1} g(s)\cdot f(s) \mathrm{d} s$ as the normal $L^p$ space.

---

Sorry about the length of this question. I try to write out what I can get so far. If you have any insights, please share with me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: First> Your guess is correct. Second: If I recall correctly, the duality for Banach space valued $L^p$ spaces doesn't hold for every Banach space, you need the space yo satisfy the "Radon Nykodim property" (RNP) which gives you 2.

Comment: @Adrian are you sure the guess is correct? If $f\in L^{p}([0,1],X)$ then $\|f\|_{X}<\infty\implies f\in X$ and so $L^{p}([0,1],X)\subseteq X$. So every $\varphi\in X^{*}$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^{p}([0,1],X)$. Also by the same as above $L^{q}([0,1],X^{*})\subseteq X^{*}$ so you may miss elements of the dual of $L^{p}([0,1],X)$ if you only aim for $L^{q}([0,1],X^{*})$. It seems that the dual space should be $L^{q}(X^{*},[0,1])$.

Comment: Of course Im sure. Look at Theorem 1.3.10 of Hytonen.Neerven-Weiss "Analysis in Banach Spaces" volume 1. I don't really understand your objection. What is $L^q(X^\ast,[0,1])$?

Comment: Would this mean that $L^{q}([0,1],X^{*})$ and $X^{*}$ are isomorphic?

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez Thank you, Adrián! I haven't learn "Radon Nykodim property " before. Could you please provide me with some reference about RNP? Like basic definition and how it relates to 2. Thanks!

Comment: @Zeta-Squared What do you mean of $f\in X$? Remember f is a path in $X$. Do you mean $f(t) \in X$ for every $t \in [0,1]$? $\left.L^{p}(0,1], X\right) \subseteq X$ doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared I am sorry about maybe I didn't make it clear in my description of problem, which may lead you to some misunderstandings of notation.

Comment: @Edward Ah! $f$ maps into $X$ sorry I misunderstood the problem. Either way this is something I have never encountered (I have not had the need to work on $L^{p}$ spaces that map into Banach spaces). I was just curious about this question. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared :) I am also curious about this question. I think Adrián is right, maybe it is not possible to determine dual space w.r.t general Banach space $X$. At least some properties such as RNP mentioned by Adrián should be attached to make the argument of 2 goes through.

Comment: A proof is given  in Theorem IV 1.1 (page 98) of the text reviewed [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183540941).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you, David. Let me try to read the text and absorb the idea. It is good to see that RNP is a necessary and sufficient condition for $L^p([0,1],X)^* = L^q([0,1],X^*)$.